# No module named tensorflow after installation?

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

I installed tensorflow-gpu but I got error in Pycharm:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I checked in terminal:

```
$ pip3 list|grep tensorflow
tensorflow-gpu                     1.4.0     
tensorflow-tensorboard             0.4.0
```

Edit: ( after installation using venv):

```
Successfully installed tensorflow-gpu-1.12.0
(venv) wojtek@wojtek-GF63-8RC:~$ python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
2018-12-17 21:49:14.893016: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-12-17 21:49:14.961123: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-12-17 21:49:14.961466: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.493
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 3.95GiB freeMemory: 3.58GiB
2018-12-17 21:49:14.961479: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-12-17 21:49:15.148507: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-12-17 21:49:15.148538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2018-12-17 21:49:15.148544: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2018-12-17 21:49:15.148687: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3306 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
tf.Tensor(918.94904, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: restart your IDE.

Comment: Can you explain how should I do it?

Comment: File->Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Just Restart.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' :(

Comment: How you installed the packages?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mind? I don't know.

Comment: I mean How you installed Tensorflow and Tensorboard. In the virtual env or directly from terminal or etc?

Comment: I installed directly from terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to configure the interpreter [src](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)

> 1) In the Project Interpreters page, select one of the configured interpreters or virtual environments.
>
> 2) Click Edit.
>
> 3) In the Edit Python Interpreter dialog box that opens, type the desired interpreter name.
>       Changing interpreter's name
>
> The Python interpreter name specified in the Name field, becomes visible in the list of available interpreters.
>
> If necessary, change the path to the Python executable.